# Can download but file will not unzip as expected

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I'm attempting to access the Geometadb database which first involves download of the SQL library. I did that and then I got the Geometadb library.

```
library(GEOmetadb)
```

Next I need the Geometadb file which is where things start to go wrong. I issue this command as seen exactly in the tutorial: https://bioconductor.riken.jp/packages/3.0/bioc/vignettes/GEOmetadb/inst/doc/GEOmetadb.html

```
if(!file.exists('GEOmetadb.sqlite')) getSQLiteFile()
```

It should proceed to not only download a .gz zip file but also unzip the file. It downloads it but never unzips it. Instead I get the following error.

```
trying URL 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51653511/GEOmetadb.sqlite.gz'
Error in download.file(url_geo, destfile = localfile, mode = "wb") : 
cannot open URL 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51653511/GEOmetadb.sqlite.gz'
In addition: Warning message:
In url(url_geo_2, open = "rb") :
cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Just not sure what's going on here. Considering these are just the early tutorial steps I'm probably missing something really obvious but I'm hoping someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: can you unzip the file outside your app? to test the files is OK? Last time I have to download a new WinRar because files where compress with a new algorithm and old version couldnt open it.

Comment: Do you mean trying to decompress it on the terminal or trying a function to unzip it on R? I tried looking into a few on R like gunzip() but it didn't work because I think the file needs to be downloaded and uncompressed all in one step.

Comment: That error message sure makes it sound like it cannot download the file. Are you sure it's downloading to where you think it's downloading? Have you deleted the file and tried again?

Comment: Yes, I've made sure the file is actually downloading. It's just downloading as a .gz which I believe means it's not unzipping. I have also deleted it and re-downloaded it several times.